# Formula to calculate number of positions in backgammon

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

In the backgammon game, 15 white and 15 black checkers stand on 24 squares so that each square is either empty, or occupied by several white checkers, or occupied by several black checkers.
How many ways are there to arrange the checkers on the board?

Resulting formula must contain at most 1 summation symbol.

I tried to transform a formula:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{22}\sum_{j=1}^{min(15, 24-i-1)}\binom{24}{i}\binom{24-i}{j} \binom{j+14}{14}\binom{24-(i+j)-1}{14}$$
, where $i$ is number of empty and $j$ is number of black.

It seems to be correct but very hard to analyze.

Comment: What have you tried so far? A clear summary will help us craft answers that are useful to you. You can tell us what you've tried by clicking "Edit" beneath your question.

Comment: In backgammon, some of the pieces may also be "on the bar," that is waiting to come onto the board, or out of the game entirely.  Are you ignoring those possibilities entirely?

Comment: All 30 pieces must be on the board.

Comment: (In backgammon there are also hard caps on how many pieces can be in a given slot; it sounds like this question is simplifying that away too.)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki There are no such limits in any backgammon game I've every played.  You can have all $15$ men on one point.  You just can't have both black and white men on the same point.

Comment: There's no reason to have two summation signs to begin with.  Pick the number of points $i$ that the black men will actually occupy.  (This is a number from $1$ to $15$.)  Then the white men will be placed the remaining $24-i$ points.  We needn't worry about which of those points they are actually placed on.

Comment: @saulspatz I was just starting to write that up as an answer; would you like to do so?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki No, thank.  Go right ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, a reframing might help: first, 'choose' (i.e., sum over) $p$ between $1$ and $15$. This will be the number of points occupied by black checkers. Next, determine what points those will be; there are clearly $24\choose p$ ways of doing that. Next, allocate the $15$ black checkers between those $p$ points, being sure to allocate at least one to each point. (Stars-and-bars or similar should be helpful for finding this binomial coefficient). Finally, allocate the $15$ white checkers between the $24-p$ remaining points. Can you build the sum from here?

Comment: There are $24^{15}$ ways of placing 15 black checkers on 24 positions (if you have a bad game you could end up with all 15 of your checkers stuck on the one point). In actual fact, since we have to include the bar (0 position) and the home (25 position) there are $26^{15}$ ways of placing 15 black checkers. So I do not understand why you are using the binomial coefficient $\binom{24}{p}$.

Comment: @TedBlack There aren't $24^{15}$ because the black checkers are indistinguishable. Consider, for instance, three checkers on four positions; then your formula would give $4^3=64$, but in fact there are 4 ways of putting all three checkers on one point, 4*3=12 ways of putting two on one point and one on a second, and 4 ways of putting one each on three points, for a total of 20 ways.

Comment: Valid point but since their are indistinguishable it should be something like $\binom{24+14}{15}$. This tallies with the fact that if we had to place 3 identical pieces in 3 positions there would be 10 different ways to do that. But then we need to add the bar and home position which means the 15 bar pieces can be split between the 24 points of the board, the bar and the home position.

Answer (score 0):

The reasoning behind Steven's answer is absolutely correct, he just missed a couple of things. First, we have to consider not only the 24 normal positions but also the position of dead checkers and the position of beared off checkers, where black and white can coexist. Then we have to find a formula that gives us the number of ways $n$ checkers can stand on $m$ positions, we can do that recursively. We can have $n,n-1,n-2,..,1,0$ checkers standing on the first positions and the others standing on the following $m-1$ positions so $f(n,m)=f(0,m-1)+f(1,m-1)+...+f(n-1,m-1)+f(n,m-1)$. We notice that all the terms but the last form $f(n-1,m)$, so $f(n,m)=f(n-1,m)+f(n,m-1)$. Knowing that $f(n,1)=f(0,m)=1$ we can build a table for $n$ and $m$ where the diagonals are the raws of the Pascal's triangle and $m$ starts from 1 instead of 0. So we can extrapolate the formula from the binomial coefficent and the formula is $f(n,m)=\binom{n+m-1}{n}=(\binom{m}{n})$.
Now it's all pretty easy, we sum up $p$ from 0 to 15, which represents the number of normal positions occupied by black, we chose $p$ positions where to put one black checker on each, which can be made in $\binom{24}{p}$ ways. The remaining $15-p$ black checkers are going to be distributed on the $p$ position occupied by one black checker plus the two other positions(dead and beared off), which can be made in $(\binom{p+2}{15-p})$ ways. The 15 white checkers can be distributed in $(\binom{26-p}{15})$ ways. So the formula is $$\sum_{p=0}^{15}\binom{24}{p}(\binom{p+2}{15-p})(\binom{26-p}{15})=18528584051601162496$$ which can be also written as $$\sum_{p=0}^{15}\binom{24}{p}\binom{16}{15-p}\binom{40-p}{15}=1.8528584051601162496 * 10^{19}$$